# Can you help me identify what supernatural anime with white-haired protagonist this is?

Tags: tactics

It's supernatural and the main protagonist has white hair. He's a guy, wearing traditional clothes, and the setting is old. He solves mysteries in towns - mostly spirits. In one episode they went to a doll maker's house.
What anime is this?

Comment: That's a big vague. The description can fit a bunch of different anime - do you have any other details?

Comment: The first one the comes to my mind is D.Gray-Man

Comment: @Oded that's all I can remember but he looks like a kid he's wearing japanese traditional clothes i think he's a priest/monk

Comment: Although the protagonist does not wear traditional Japanese clothes.... Maybe Mushishi?

Comment: @JNat no it's just new i think thanks though

Comment: @nikita It's more recent than Mushishi? Did it come out this season, maybe? When did you first see it?

Comment: @JNat - I wrote that before it was clear that the tradition involved was Japanese ;)

Comment: @Oded Yeah, I meant the protagonist from Mushishi does not wear traditional Japanese clothes. I was not referring to your comment ;)

Comment: Is it Mononoke? I don't remember a doll maker arc in that show though.

Comment: Can you give me/us some more details like: is his hair long or short? Color of his eyes? It will make search easier. ^^

Answer (score 5):

I believe it's *Tactics*. Episode 5 features a doll-maker, and seems to fit your description perfectly.

[image: Tactics]

Answer (score 1):

I think the anime is [Inuyasha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InuYasha). Here's the blurb from [MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/249/InuYasha).

> Higurashi Kagome, after being pulled down a well by a demon, finds herself in Feudal Japan, where she learns that a powerful jewel has been reborn inside her body. After the jewel shatters in an attempt to retrieve it from one of the many demons who was after its power, Kagome must join forces with the half-demon Inu Yasha (also after the jewel's power) to track down the shards of the jewel before its power falls into the wrong hands.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about Ginko from Mushishi.

[image: Ginko-Mushishi]

Comment: He is not, check out the comment thread below the OP.